# flipclock.js time lags behind if you use 2 differend windows on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flipclock

I'm using flipclock for a project and i have 2 tabs with the same clock countdown that starts at the same time. The problem is that on chrome it does not sync corectly. At one of them time lag behind. Even if you open two http://flipclockjs.com/ windows after few minutes one of them lag behind. Did someone else had this problem on chrome? on Firefox works good